# Stackoverflow error while generating a set of 2 non repeated random numbers from a range of numbers

Tags: java, android, random, stack-overflow

Below are the 2 methods which I am using to generate a random number from a range of numbers.This is part of a small maths quiz. The number of questions can go upto 50 questions. The only clause is the numbers should be non repeated i.e 5x6 if is present in the list I cant have 6x5 in the list.

The problem that I am facing is the below code throws stackoverflow error.I have tried to run it in a separate thread but I am unable to get it working.

The for loop used inside the first method is the one I use to check if the number is already present.

```
public QuestionsV1 generateQuestionsArray(int level, int range) {
generateRandomNumbers(level, range);
    for (QuestionsV1 questions : questionsList) {
        if (questionsList != null && ((first_number == questions.getFirst_number() && second_number == questions.getSecond_number())
                || (first_number == questions.getSecond_number() &&
                second_number == questions.getFirst_number()))) {
            generateQuestionsArray(level, range);
            break;
        }
    }
    Log.d("ArrayList---", first_number + " " + second_number);
    QuestionsV1 questions = new QuestionsV1();
    questions.setFirst_number(first_number);
    questions.setSecond_number(second_number);
    questions.setOperator("x");
    questions.setCorrect_answer(first_number * second_number);
    return questions;
}


public void generateRandomNumbers(int level, int range) {
    Random rand1 = new Random();
    Random rand2 = new Random();
    if (range == 0) {
        first_number = rand1.nextInt(3 - 1 + 1) + 1;
    } else if (range == 1) {
        first_number = rand1.nextInt(6 - 4 + 1) + 4;
    } else if (range == 2) {
        first_number = rand1.nextInt(10 - 7 + 1) + 7;
    }
    switch (level) {
        case 1:
            second_number = rand2.nextInt(6 - 2 + 1) + 2;
            break;
        case 2:
            second_number = rand2.nextInt(12 - 7 + 1) + 7;
            break;
        case 3:
            second_number = rand2.nextInt(20 - 13 + 1) + 13;
            break;

    }
```

below is the error which I am getting.

```
   Fatal Exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 2MB
   at java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong.<init>(AtomicLong.java:61)
   at java.util.Random.<init>(Random.java:137)
   at java.util.Random.<init>(Random.java:105)
   at com.leapscale.scimat.t4e.Builders.Multiply.generateRandomNumbers(Multiply.java:80)
   at com.leapscale.scimat.t4e.Builders.Multiply.generateRandomNumbers(Multiply.java:106)
   at com.leapscale.scimat.t4e.Builders.Multiply.generateRandomNumbers(Multiply.java:106)
   at com.leapscale.scimat.t4e.Builders.Multiply.generateRandomNumbers(Multiply.java:106)
   at com.leapscale.scimat.t4e.Builders.Multiply.generateRandomNumbers(Multiply.java:106)
   at com.leapscale.scimat.t4e.Builders.Multiply.generateRandomNumbers(Multiply.java:106)
   at com.leapscale.scimat.t4e.Builders.Multiply.generateRandomNumbers(Multiply.java:106)
   at com.leapscale.scimat.t4e.Builders.Multiply.generateRandomNumbers(Multiply.java:106)
   at com.leapscale.scimat.t4e.Builders.Multiply.generateRandomNumbers(Multiply.java:106)
   at com.leapscale.scimat.t4e.Builders.Multiply.generateRandomNumbers(Multiply.java:106)
   at com.leapscale.scimat.t4e.Builders.Multiply.generateRandomNumbers(Multiply.java:106)
   at com.leapscale.scimat.t4e.Builders.Multiply.generateQuestionsArray(Multiply.java:39)
   at com.leapscale.scimat.t4e.Builders.Multiply.generateRandomNumbersHard(Multiply.java:74)
   at com.leapscale.scimat.t4e.Builders.Multiply.calculateNoOfQuestionsForLevels(Multiply.java:141)
   at com.leapscale.scimat.t4e.Builders.Multiply.getList(Multiply.java:146)
   at com.leapscale.scimat.t4e.Levels.Levels_Fragment$QuestionBuilder$1.run(Levels_Fragment.java:185)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: You probably don't want to call `generateQuestionsArray(level, range);` inside itself with the exact same arguments. That's a textbook infinite recursion.

Comment: sorry my bad i have edited it..please check

Comment: @khelwood if i do not call then i wont be able to discard the currently generated number

Comment: Whatever you think it will do, this is not the way to do it.

Comment: @khelwood but this thing seems to work properly for addition subtraction and division.

Comment: @khelwood can you please elaborate as to a proper way to do it

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what your recursive call is supposed to achieve, so I can't tell you what to do instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145889/discussion-between-akshay-shah-and-khelwood).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using recursive call use a `while` loop to keep generating until a non-duplicate value is created.  Something similar to this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class App {
    private static final int QUESTION_COUNT = 25;
    private static final int RANGE = 10;
    private static final Random RAND = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.generateAndDisplayQuestions();
    }

    private void generateAndDisplayQuestions() {
        List<QuestionV1> questions = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int q = 0; q < QUESTION_COUNT; q++) {
            while(true) {
                QuestionV1 question = getNextRandomQuestion();
                if (!questions.contains(question)) {
                    questions.add(question);
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("found a duplicate - trying again...");
            }

            System.out.println("Question " + (q + 1) + ": first = " + questions.get(q).getFirst() + " : second = " + questions.get(q).getSecond());
        }
    }

    private QuestionV1 getNextRandomQuestion() {
        return new QuestionV1(RAND.nextInt(RANGE), RAND.nextInt(RANGE));
    }

    private class QuestionV1 {
        private int first;
        private int second;

        public QuestionV1(int first, int second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            QuestionV1 other = (QuestionV1)o;
            return (this.first == other.first && this.second == other.second) || (this.first == other.second && this.second == other.first);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return first * 31 + second;
        }

        public int getFirst() {
            return first;
        }

        public int getSecond() {
            return second;
        }

    }

}
```

Not that if `RANGE` is low and `QUESTION_COUNT`is high, then this will cause an infinite loop since all possible combinations will be used.